# IONIC 4 - Loading Controller In Http interceptor......Not able to create and dismiss properly due to Asynchronous call

Tags: ionic4

I want to create loader for each http call and dismiss it when reponse is there....tried some code.....which shows sometimes mulitple loaders on each other...snap is there of code..

interceptor.ts

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest < any >, next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {

  request = request.clone({
    headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
  });
  this.commonServices.showLoader();
  return next.handle(request).pipe(
    map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.commonServices.hideLoader();
      }
      return event;
    }),
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.commonServices.hideLoader();
      if (error.status === 401) {
        this.storage.clear();
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        if (error.error.success === false) {
          this.commonServices.forToast("Login failed");
        } else {
          //this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      }
      return throwError(error);
    }));
}
```

CommonService.service.ts

> ```
> async showLoader() {
>       if (!this.loader) {
>           this.loader = await this.loadingController.create({ message: 'Loading' });
>       }
>       await this.loader.present();
>   }
>
>   async hideLoader() {
>       if (this.loader) {
>           await this.loader.dismiss();
>           this.loader = null;
>       }
>   }
> ```

Comment: Have you found the solution?